# $\tilde O$ is open for an open set $O \subset R^n$, $\tilde E = \{(x,y) : x-y \in E\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I'm trying to solve the following statement:

"For $E \subset R^n$, let $\tilde E = \{(x,y) : x-y \in E\}$. If $O$ is an open set in $R^n$, show that $\tilde O$ is an open set in $R^n*R^n$."

Below is my trial...

For $(x,y) \in \tilde O$, $x-y$ is an element of $O$. So there is $r > 0$ such that $B_r(x-y) \in O$, where $B_r(w)$ implies an open ball with radius $r$ centered at $w \in R^n$. Then, for any $z \in B_r(x-y)$, $|z - (x-y)| < r$ holds. The above inequality can be written as $|z - (x-y)| = |(z+h-x) - (h-y)| < r$ for all $h \in R^n$. Then, $|z+h-x| < r$ and $|h-y| < r$ holds.

Let $\tilde z_h = (z+h,h)$, then $|\tilde z_h - (x,y)|^2 = |(z+h-x, h-y)|^2 = |z+h-x|^2+|h-y|^2 < 2r^2$, so $\tilde z_h \in B_{\sqrt 2 r}((x,y))$. Also, $(z+h) - (h) = z \in B_r(x-y)$, so $\tilde z_h \in \tilde O$.

This holds for all $z \in B_r(x-y)$ and all $h \in R^n$. So, $(x,y)$ is an interior point of $\tilde O$.

I guess my statement isn't clear enough to prove the $(x,y)$ is an interior point of $\tilde O$. Any comments about my trial, or other aproaches would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps E is O?

Comment: $E$ is just a general set in $R^n$. I stated the set $E$ to explain the definition of $\tilde E$.

Comment: What do you know about the function $p: \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n, p(x,y) = x-y$ ?

Comment: BTW, I assumed that  your $R^n$ is $\mathbb R^n$ (MathJax: "backslash mathbb R^n") and  $R^n*R^n$ is $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$ ("backslash times"). Is this correct?

Comment: yes, and your funtion $p$ is continuous, then $\tilde O$ would be written as $p^{-1}(O)$. Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes, you got it!

Comment: Ok, I understand it, Thanks a lot.